# How to design multiple child tables against a single parent table?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I'd be grateful if someone could advise me what the correct way is to approach this:

- I have a parent table, with primary key `master_id`.
- I have five child tables associated with the master_id, in a 1-to-n relationship, that record semantically different types of data (and wouldn't lend themselves to abstraction)
- The only common fields in each child table are `master-id` (foreign key), `created_by` (user_id), `created_time` (timestamp).

The aim is to publish each child row associated with a master id in a chronological order on a webpage (imagine a forum posts style display), with the PHP building each "post" (i.e. row) slightly differently depending on the child table (and hence fields of data available to it).

Am I right in thinking there's no easy way to query this regardless of the table structure (and that ordering would be best done in PHP)? Is there any advantage to vertically partitioning out the 3 common fields into a single table combined with a `table` field?

Comment: Would a view do what you need it to do? I was faced with a similar situation and found that instead of trying to normalize the data itself, I could compile it into the format I wanted through the view and leave everything as it was.

Comment: You can do it using a `UNION` subquery, ordering the combined results in the parent query.  You may have to insert extra columns into each query so that the resultsets align.  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10324939/623041) for more information.

Comment: @eggyal I read your other answer, thanks. I decided against it in the end because 1. if further child tables are ever added, the null columns in each select resulstet would become increasingly laborious to maintain, and 2. every table would need querying which is a performance overhead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a really difficult problem to solve, one I've worked on myself.  Unfortunately, I don't have a good answer.  You could use UNIONs and various types of JOINs, but you're going to potentially heavily kill your database's performance.  Plus, you run into issues like, say you want the most 30 recent chronological entries.  You'd have to query every child table for 30 entries (possibly 150 entries in all) and sort through them in your code since you don't know which child table(s) have the most recent 30 entries.  150 rows just to pull 30, blech.

Honestly, the best way I've found to implement such a thing is to have a table, possibly your master table, have columns dedicated specifically to what you want to show from your child table.  For example, have columns in your master table that are something like, `master_id`, `created_by`, `created_time`, and `notification_text` (if you're trying to implement something like Facebook's timeline, for example).  You could set up triggers on the child tables so that when you insert data into one of them, it automatically populates the data in the master table as well.  Then when you're displaying the timeline, you just query the master table without bothering with the child tables at all.

Your schema would look something like:

```
Table master
- master_id
- created_by
- created_time
- notification_text

Table child1
- id
- master_id
- data1 (used to generate notification_text in master)

Table child2
- id
- master_id
- data21 (collectively used to generate notification_text in master)
- data22 (collectively used to generate notification_text in master)
- data23 (collectively used to generate notification_text in master)

...
```

Comment: Hi King - I've decided to try this denormalization-oriented approach. I've extended the idea a little to have further columns like 'notification_title', 'notification_content' etc to allow a little more flexibility on the page. An alternative solution might also be to use a master table with a table field for the purposes of the most recent ids and their location, then send repeat queries from the php. Not ideal either though.

Comment: I feel your pain.  I'm working on a Facebook-like social network site for a gaming community, and I've run into this exact issue.  The advantage of denormalization is performance--you only have to run the one query against the one table, and with indexes, it can be extremely efficient.  In my project, I decided that was the way to go for the sheer number of other tables for all of the different types of events could possibly trigger notifications.  Unfortunately--or maybe fortunately--I don't think any mainstream database supports indirect references to tables, like we'd need in an ideal case.

Answer (score 0):

What about you do a star model? It's commonly use to create datawarehouses however you could try to use something similar in your solution. If you are not familiar with the star model you can see more [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_schema).

Hope it helps.